# Does Cloud Python lib in GAE use caching or memcache for access to Cloud Firestore data?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-python, google-cloud-firestore

Setup: Google App Engine application on Python standard environment.

Currently, the app uses the NDB library to read/write from its Datastore. It uses async tasklets for parallel, asynchronous reads from Datastore, and memcache.

If I would like to use Firestore as a replacement for Datastore, it seems that I would have to use the Google Cloud Client Library for Python. I believe that the google-cloud lib doesn't support a mechanism like tasklets. But I wonder: Does the lib use a thread-safe cache-mechanism for its requests to the Firestore API, and maybe even GAE's memcache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Firestore server-side client libraries are not optimized for App Engine Standard. They  don't integrate with a caching solution like GAE's memcache; you'd have to write that layer yourself.

Comment: I was under the impression that since the Firestore library is part of the Google Cloud library, it wasn't supported on App Engine standard with Python (due to the underlying use of gRPC and incompatibilities with Python on GAE Standard) [ref1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/-69J7mSaeAU/mhW9c-vRAgAJ) [ref2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1200#issuecomment-342232540)